# How to make leaf of Primefaces Tree component as Commandlink

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm generating Primefaces Tree component as

```
root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
List<String> categories = reportService.getCategories();

    for (String categoryName : categories) {
        TreeNode Rnode = new DefaultTreeNode(categoryName, root);
        List<String> reportNames = reportService
                .getReportNames(categoryName);

        for (String reportName : reportNames) {
            Rnode.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode(reportName));
        }
    }
```

and Xhtml looks like this

```
    <p:tree value="#{reportManagedBean.root}" var="node">
        <p:treeNode>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{node}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
```

How do I make only the leaf node as CommandLink and rest as OutputLabel?

Comment: Did you try to use different [node types](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/tree?id=multiple-treenode-types)?

Comment: @Selaron Thanks for commenting, but Node Types will not serve the purpose.

Comment: Did you try `c:if` / `c:choose`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nodeVar` attribute to access the current `TreeNode` instance and determine whether or not the current node is a leaf:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tree value="#{reportManagedBean.root}" var="data" nodeVar="node">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{data}"
                rendered="#{not empty node.children}" />
            <h:commandLink value="Do something: #{data}"
                rendered="#{empty node.children}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Rather than using `Rnode.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode(reportName));`, I would use `new DefaultTreeNode(reportName, RNode)`.
2. To make the leaf as CommandLink, you need conditional statement. So you can either use `nodeVar` or have a property to flag if the object is a child.